# Do Thomas the Tank Engine Duplo trains seat figures?

Tags: trains, duplo

Lego made Thomas the Tank Engine licensed Duplo sets in the 2000's decade at the same scale as current Duplo trains. Do the Thomas trains seat Duplo figures like current trains do? I've seen some pictures of disassembled Thomas trains (e.g. in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIP4KPE6Mmc) video) that seem to indicate that there is space under the roof of the train, but all of the Thomas trains seem to have opaque windows, possibly implying that adding figures was not a priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The train bodies do indeed consist of a stack of 4x4 "blocks" that were fully enclosed when assembled - and as I recall, we could fit a seated Duplo character within most of the cab sections.

Toby and the coaches had the most room, but most engines just about had room.